# How to mark date using TapkuCalendar

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3

i want mark my calendar by date that saved in plist

[image]

and i put this code inside marksFromDate

```
- (NSArray*)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView marksFromDate:(NSDate *)startDate toDate:(NSDate *)lastDate
{        
    NSString *documentDirectory = [self applicationDocumentsDirectory];
    NSString *path = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PlainNotes.plist"];
    NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    self.Notes = tmpArray;
    NSString *date = [tmpArray valueForKey:@"CDate"];

    NSArray *data = [NSArray arrayWithObject:date];
    NSLog(@"Mark for this date %@", data);

    // Initialise empty marks array, this will be populated with TRUE/FALSE in order for each day a marker should be placed on.
    NSMutableArray *marks = [NSMutableArray array];

    // Initialise calendar to current type and set the timezone to never have daylight saving
    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    [cal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

    // Construct DateComponents based on startDate so the iterating date can be created.
    // Its massively important to do this assigning via the NSCalendar and NSDateComponents because of daylight saving has been removed 
    // with the timezone that was set above. If you just used "startDate" directly (ie, NSDate *date = startDate;) as the first 
    // iterating date then times would go up and down based on daylight savings.
    NSDateComponents *comp = [cal components:(NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | 
                                              NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) 
                                    fromDate:startDate];
    NSDate *d = [cal dateFromComponents:comp];

    // Init offset components to increment days in the loop by one each time
    NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [offsetComponents setDay:1];    


    // for each date between start date and end date check if they exist in the data array
    while (YES) {
        // Is the date beyond the last date? If so, exit the loop.
        // NSOrderedDescending = the left value is greater than the right
        if ([d compare:lastDate] == NSOrderedDescending) {
            break;
        }

        // If the date is in the data array, add it to the marks array, else don't
        if ([data containsObject:[d description]]) {
            [marks addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
        } else {
            [marks addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
        }

        // Increment day using offset components (ie, 1 day in this instance)
        d = [cal dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:d options:0];
    }


    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:marks];
}
```

And this is for log

```
2012-08-19 17:10:50.168 PlainNotes[2852:f803] Mark for this date (
        (
        "2012-08-19 00:00:00 +0000",
        "2012-08-31 00:00:00 +0000"
    )
)
```

This didn't mark my calendar but this below code is from TapkuCalendar

```
- (NSArray*)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView marksFromDate:(NSDate *)startDate toDate:(NSDate *)lastDate {    
    NSLog(@"calendarMonthView marksFromDate toDate");   
    NSLog(@"Make sure to update 'data' variable to pull from CoreData, website, User Defaults, or some other source.");
    // When testing initially you will have to update the dates in this array so they are visible at the
    // time frame you are testing the code.
    NSArray *data = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     @"2011-01-01 00:00:00 +0000", @"2011-01-09 00:00:00 +0000", @"2011-01-22 00:00:00 +0000",
                     @"2011-01-10 00:00:00 +0000", @"2011-01-11 00:00:00 +0000", @"2011-01-12 00:00:00 +0000",
                     @"2011-01-15 00:00:00 +0000", @"2011-01-28 00:00:00 +0000", @"2011-01-04 00:00:00 +0000",                   
                     @"2011-01-16 00:00:00 +0000", @"2011-01-18 00:00:00 +0000", @"2011-01-19 00:00:00 +0000",                   
                     @"2011-01-23 00:00:00 +0000", @"2011-01-24 00:00:00 +0000", @"2011-01-25 00:00:00 +0000",                                       
                     @"2011-02-01 00:00:00 +0000", @"2011-03-01 00:00:00 +0000", @"2011-04-01 00:00:00 +0000",
                     @"2011-05-01 00:00:00 +0000", @"2011-06-01 00:00:00 +0000", @"2011-07-01 00:00:00 +0000",
                     @"2011-08-01 00:00:00 +0000", @"2011-09-01 00:00:00 +0000", @"2011-10-01 00:00:00 +0000",
                     @"2011-11-01 00:00:00 +0000", @"2011-12-01 00:00:00 +0000", nil]; 
    NSLog(@"Mark for this date %@", data);
```

And this is for TapkuCalendar log

```
2012-08-19 17:01:08.604 TapkuCalendarTabBarDemo[2807:f803] calendarMonthView marksFromDate toDate
2012-08-19 17:01:08.605 TapkuCalendarTabBarDemo[2807:f803] Make sure to update 'data' variable to pull from CoreData, website, User Defaults, or some other source.
2012-08-19 17:01:08.606 TapkuCalendarTabBarDemo[2807:f803] Mark for this date (
    "2011-01-01 00:00:00 +0000",
    "2011-01-09 00:00:00 +0000",
    "2011-01-22 00:00:00 +0000",
    "2011-01-10 00:00:00 +0000",
    "2011-01-11 00:00:00 +0000",
    "2011-01-12 00:00:00 +0000",
    "2011-01-15 00:00:00 +0000",
    "2011-01-28 00:00:00 +0000",
    "2011-01-04 00:00:00 +0000",
    "2011-01-16 00:00:00 +0000",
    "2011-01-18 00:00:00 +0000",
    "2011-01-19 00:00:00 +0000",
    "2011-01-23 00:00:00 +0000",
    "2011-01-24 00:00:00 +0000",
    "2011-01-25 00:00:00 +0000",
    "2011-02-01 00:00:00 +0000",
    "2011-03-01 00:00:00 +0000",
    "2011-04-01 00:00:00 +0000",
    "2011-05-01 00:00:00 +0000",
    "2011-06-01 00:00:00 +0000",
    "2011-07-01 00:00:00 +0000",
    "2011-08-01 00:00:00 +0000",
    "2011-09-01 00:00:00 +0000",
    "2011-10-01 00:00:00 +0000",
    "2011-11-01 00:00:00 +0000",
    "2011-12-01 00:00:00 +0000"
)
```

What i see in here is both of mine and TapkuCalendar log is same, but why my code can't mark the calendar? How to fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The method is defined as `-(NSArray*)...` so my initial concern would be that you're not returning anything.

Try adding `return data;` to the end of `calendarMonthView:marksFromDate:toDate:`.    `

Comment: it still same, actually theres already return for marksFromDate. This is weird.

Comment: You need to show all the code. At the minute you're only showing one `NSArray *data = [NSArray arrayWithObject:date];` but your data has at least 2 dates in it. There's no iteration or anything to show you're doing this. Post the entire method.

Comment: sir, i am sorry, just to clarify, both my code is same as TapkuCalendar's use it. The different part that is my project using CDate in plist for mark the calendar not writen as TapkuCalendar does in marksFromDate. I can send it both file for you if you need it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I already solve it. I change my NSString to NSArray like code below.

```
NSArray *data = [Notes valueForKeyPath:@"CDate"];
NSLog(@"Mark for this date %@", data);
```

Thank you for all help. I really appreciate. Sorry for my stupid question. I just a newbie.